# Why Extensions menu isnt' shown?

Tags: web, content-management-system, joomla, joomla1.5

in a website developed with Joomla CMS (1.5.15 version) in the admin panel the extensions menu (necessary to install extensions, templates and so on) isn't shown.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to update to 1.5.22. It's very easy to do and you are extremely vulnerable considering there have been 7 security updates since your version.

Next, those menu items are not available to all administrators, only super admins. Here's a good summary of back end permissions - http://help.joomla.org/content/view/228/153/1/2/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Tmp and logs directories path was wrong so Joomla wasn't able to install the component because it could not extract the archive of the component.